# ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from Dialog

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

when I add

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/compose_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

to XML I am getting above error. I tried to update appcompat library but it didnt worked.Anyone have sollution?

Answer (score 2):

You should bind lifecycleOwner to the root view of the dialog.

```kotlin
ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(view, lifecycleOwner)
```

For me, I use a custom compose view in `AlertDialog` from the dialog builder.

```kotlin
AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.my_style) {
    setTitle("title")
    setMessage("message")
    setView(myCustomView)
}.create().apply {
    window?.let {
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(it.decorView, activity as LifecycleOwner)
        it.decorView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(activity as SavedStateRegistryOwner)
    }
}
```

If you use `DialogFragment`, I think you could do the same thing in

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(view, activity as LifecycleOwner)
    view.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(activity as SavedStateRegistryOwner)
}
```

Comment: I can see dialog or alert but it shows nothing or my view in Composeview is not showing. If I use setContentView(xml), my xml view shows correctly

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to make Compose UI work inside a View-based `AlertDialog` (neither the platform version nor AppCompat's variant). If you want to use Compose UI in a dialog-like component, there are two ways to make it work.

#### Option 1

If your screen's UI is Compose already, use the `AlertDialog` composable function in a declarative way and skip the need for XML altogether:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
  var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

  if (showDialog) {
    AlertDialog(
      onDismissRequest = { showDialog = false },
      confirmButton = {
        TextButton(
          text = "OK",
          onClick = { showDialog = false },
        )
      },
      title = { /* Your dialog's content here... */ },
      text = { /* and/or here... */ },
    )
  }

  // Screen's UI goes here
  Button(onClick = { showDialog = true }) {
    Text("Click me to show a dialog")
  }
}
```

#### Option 2

If you need to show the dialog even in scenarios where Option 1 isn't really possible, consider using a `DialogFragment` instead of the View-based `AlertDialog` class. Since a dialog fragment is a `Fragment`, it has access to the `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner` that Compose expects:

```kotlin
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): ComposeView {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).also {
      it.clipToPadding = false
    }
  }

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    (view as ComposeView).setContent {
      // Your dialog's content here
    }
  }
}
```

When you need to show `MyDialogFragment` on screen:

```kotlin
// From an activity
MyDialogFragment().show(this.supportFragmentManager, "dialog-tag")

// From a fragment
MyDialogFragment(this.childFragmentManager, "dialog-tag")
```

Comment: Are you sure about second option is working? I remembered I did same but not worked. I just want to use BounceView library in my dialogs. https://github.com/hariprasanths/Bounceview-Android

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I am using several DialogFragments with Compose in my applications without issues. It might be worth trying again with your updated dependencies (for the record, I use AndroidX Fragment 1.5.4 and AppCompat 1.5.1 at the moment).

Comment: I tried that it is showing dialog but composeview content which is 
(view as ComposeView).setContent {
      // Your dialog's content here
    } 
not showing. If I use setcontentview(XML) its working

Answer (score 0):

Currently AppCompatDialog which extends ComponentDialog had a LifeCycleOwner bug because it didn't forward setContent call to it's super, causing LifeCycleOwner missing https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261314581

You can inject it yourself by doing this before setConentView()

```
fun injectViewTree() {
  try {
    window!!.decorView.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(this)
    window!!.decorView.setViewTreeOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner(this)
    window!!.decorView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(ownerActivity as ComponentActivity)
    window!!.decorView.setViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner(ownerActivity as ComponentActivity)
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("BaseMvpDialogExt", "injectViewTree", e)
  }
}
```

Then call in your custom dialog, call it before setContent

```
    injectViewTree(this);
    setContentView(viewDataBinding.getRoot());
```